# I want to learn programming I'm new here can anyone tell me how should I start?

Tags: new-operator

I want to learn about programming I'm new to this field so it will be greatful if you guys can suggest what should I start with.

Comment: What do you want to do with programming?  Are you looking to make it a hobby or a job?

Comment: Guess that you should give a bit more of focus to get proper support. There are several platforms, languages, technologies out there...

Comment: I want to become a game developer. Currently I'm in university it's my first year so at some point I have to do it. Therefore i want to start from now. So yeah I want it for job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start by choosing a patform and an app to build. Practice makes perfect. If ur phone is on android than start building a copy of an app that u like in Kotlin or if ur phone is Iphone then start building that app in swift ( you do need a macbook laptop or pc to develop in XCode). I was a total beginner at the start of the pandemic last year in march. And since then i learned on my own how to program in java, kotlin , swift ,node and javascript. That means almost 10 months of learning, deleting the whole project and starting again from scratch and finished building my own app and im going to launch it next month. But again practice pratice practice. Im not a professional developer atm but im at least mid level now. So for Kotlin u can use Android Studio or Intellij Ideea software and for ios is Xcode. Also there are loads of tutorials and help on google and youtube. You just need to start and write your first code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very helpful blog that provides a road map to becoming a full stack web developer. It covers FE and BE technologies (I would pick the one that sounds most appealing to you and dedicate the year to becoming either a great FE developer or a BE one) - https://medium.com/swlh/2021-js-fullstack-web-developer-roadmap-part1-d86ac51d5c39

As a FE developer I started with HTML, CSS and JavaScript and only once comfortable with the following did I start to look at libraries such as React.

Udemy has a great selection of courses and they usually always have a sale on.

The text editor that I use is https://code.visualstudio.com/

Remember to practice what you learn and be patient with yourself as programming is challenging, but the rewards are worth it! :)

Answer (score 0):

first, choose a platform you have some passion for, either app development, desktop development, or web development
apps development: ios, android or both

ios: you need a mac, learn swift(better) or objective C

android: works on any os you need to learn kotlin(the best) or java(not recommended)

both: you can program for both os by learning flutter(supported by Google), react native(you need to learn javascript), or Xamarin(supported by Microsoft)

I don't know a lot about desktop development

web development: two sections front end or back end
the front end is the part that takes care of the part of the user interaction like button or views etc, you need to learn HTML, CSS, and javascript

backend is the part that takes part of behind the scenes like signing the user remotely or taking information from a network sever

hope you succeed in your journey

Comment: thank you so much, my young brother found what he really love